# SQL Statement to compare timing with value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having this issue with an sql statement. The table looks something like this:

- Racer(racerid,name)
- Matches(matchid,racerid,timeInSeconds)

My question is, let's say there's a racer named 'Alex'. Is there a possible query to find a racer that beats 'Alex' in at least 4 of these matches. (Meaning the timeInSeconds is smaller)

I know this may seemed like a really simple query but I just can't seem to get my head around it and I can't seem to look for an answer for this as well. (Might be because I'm really clueless what to search.)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have tagged MySQL and SQL Server. Which one is it?

Comment: It appears you are using two tables in one database. Is there one entry for each match or one for each participant? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi Fred, I'm sorry but it's MySQL! 

Hi Andy, Yes. It's two tables in a database which would most likely have to be joined. There are multiple entries for each racer under the table 'Racer' and matches and stored in the 'Matches' table if that's what you're asking.

What I'm trying to query back is the names of racers that beats 'Alex' timing in at least 4 different matches.

Comment: @Xyles have you tried out my query? does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Because Chris P is pushing this, this answer is for **MySQL** but since both MySQL and SQL Server are tagged its hard to tell which technology you are using. 
one way to do it is use EXISTS as a filtering subquery

```
SELECT r.name
FROM racer r
JOIN matches m ON m.racerid = r.racerid
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM racer r1 
    JOIN matches m1 ON m1.racerid = r1.racerid
    WHERE r1.name = "Alex"
      AND m.timeinseconds < m1.timeinseconds
)
GROUP BY r.racerid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

[**MySQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d3168/1)

as a bonus if you want to see the average time in seconds it took the person who beat alex then you can add `AVG(m.timeinseconds)` to the select... if you want to see all of the times then you can do `GROUP_CONCAT(m.timeinseconds)` to see a comma separated list of times

---

### Edit:

if you want an answer for sql server you can as chris p noted in the comments just change the group by.. NOTE the quotation marks around Alex need to be single quotes

```
SELECT r.name
FROM racer r
JOIN matches m ON m.racerid = r.racerid
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM racer r1 
    JOIN matches m1 ON m1.racerid = r1.racerid
    WHERE r1.name = 'Alex'
      AND m.timeinseconds < m1.timeinseconds
)
GROUP BY r.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

[**SQL SERVER DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d316/3)

Comment: Query does not contain criteria for _"beats 'Alex' in at least 4 of these matches"_.

Comment: This won't give a list of racers that have beaten Alex in at least 4 races

Comment: @Fred yup as chris pointed out... i edited it to include that

Comment: Select list is incompatible with your `GROUP BY` clause for both of these queries.

Comment: @ChrisP i just tested and it returns the correct name

Comment: @JohnRuddell Your syntax appears to work in MySQL but in SQL Server it will throw an error regarding the `r.name` not being in an aggregate function. Given the question has tagged both technologies I won't vote down the answer although is technically incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisP the answer is not technically incorrect as the OP can't be using both MySQL and sql-server.. since it hasn't been clarified which one the OP is using i posted a working solution for mysql. come on.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Simply by switching `GROUP BY r.racerid` to `GROUP BY r.name` you will have an answer that works with both technologies and therefore a correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisP i tested with sql server (even though I don't use it much) and it returns an error (incorrect column name 'Alex') however the OP posted that it is MySQL in the comment below his question

Comment: @ChrisP i figured it out I had double quotes around Alex and it didn't seem to like that... is there some documentation for SQL server that requires single quotes?